# matplotlib: create multiple subplots from pandas (multiclass)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to create multiple plots from my pandas Dataframe as follows:

```
dataset.head()
   trip_id   duration     distance  avg_speed    avg_acc     travel_mode
0   303633       1.0      42.74      0.00        70.46        foot
1   303637      30.0      521.07     1.43        27.86         car
2   303638      13.0      339.58     0.65        26.30         car
3   303642      12.0      459.94     0.00        78.67         car
4   303657       4.0      71.3       0.00        72.94        foot
```

The column `travel_mode` contains 5 different transportation modes:

```
dataset.travel_mode.unique()
array(['foot', 'car', 'bus', 'bike', 'metro'], dtype=object)
```

I want to plot the distribution of `duration,  distance, avg_speed` and `avg_acc` per for each travel mode.

```
col = ['duration', 'distance', 'avg_speed', 'avg_acc', 'travel_mode']
dataset[col].groupby('travel_mode').hist(bins=50, figsize=(6, 4))
```

[image]

Figures are displayed in a way you can't tell which figure is what type of transportation. Then I tried distribution by skewness.

Distribution of skewness:

```
l = dataset.columns.values
n_cols=4
n_rows =5
plt.figure(figsize=(3*n_cols,2*n_rows))
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    plt.subplot(n_rows + 1,n_cols,i+1)
    sns.distplot(dataset[l[i]],kde=True)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

[image]

How do I display a labelled distribution per travel mode, such that travel modes are in rows and the columns display figures for `duration, distance, avg_speed,` and `avg_acc`?

Comment: Do you want to plot all histograms in one window or would one window per travel mode work?

Comment: I would like to plot one window per travel mode.

Comment: Check answer below, I am looping over the groups and changing the column names for each group dataframe to add the group name. Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a beautiful code, but you can identify the group... the title is a concatenation of the group name and the columns.

```
groups = dataset.groupby('travel_mode')
for group in groups:
    label = group[0]
    data = group[1]
    data.columns = label + " - " + data.columns
    data.hist(bins=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to separate by your `travel_mode`. Note the `subplots=True`.

```
dataset[col].groupby('travel_mode').plot(kind='hist', bins=50, subplots=True)
```

If you would like a density plot overlayed, I think it will work with seaborn:

```
df = dataset[col].melt(['travel_mode'], var_name='cols',  value_name='vals')
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='cols', row="travel_mode")
g = (g.map(sns.distplot, "vals", kde=True, bins=50))
```